# Powershell script to get FullName of a Directory tree

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to get an output of the FullName of a Folder of each level from a specific directory tree.

I want to get an output like:

```
C:\
C:\dir1
C:\dir1\dir2
C:\dir1\dir2\dir3
```

The thing is that the directory has to be specific... like the directory part between `C:\` and `C:\dir1\dir2\dir3`

Like a start path and end path, any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$Path = 'C:\dir1\dir2\dir3'

$Folders = $Path -Split "\\"
$Folders | % { $i = 0 } { $Folders[0..$i] -Join "\" -Replace ":$", ":\"; $i++ }
```

Result:

```
C:\
C:\dir1
C:\dir1\dir2
C:\dir1\dir2\dir3
```

Answer (score 2):

For PowerShell v3 or later:

```
Get-ChildItem C:\dir1 -Directory -Recurse |
  Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName
```

For older versions:

```
Get-ChildItem C:\Dir1 -Recurse |
  Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer } |
  Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName
```

Comment: ye like that but, I'm trying to get the paths only beteen dir1 and (lets say)dir10. But there are directorys which are not relevant, so only the paths beteen are in the list. I dont know how to only include those.


I tried few things with  Split-Path. I had the though of making a loop, so it repeats splitting until its path "C:\Exaple". But it kinda didnt work as expected :)

Comment: `Get-ChildItem` has an `-Exclude` parameter to exclude certain items from processing. I would suggest reading the documentation first.